# How to remove "add/remove line" button in list element gravity form?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

How to remove the "add/remove row" button in the list element of a form
How to remove this button programmatically via hook or filter?
I'm making a static table with checkboxes from a list element, so I need to remove the "add/remove row" button. (attached photo).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrZJS.png)

Help me please. (I don't want to hide it with css)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an html block to your gravity form and add the following jquery:

```
 <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("#gform_353").find('.gfield_list_icons').remove();//replace 353 with your form id 
     });
    </script>
```

You can also add the above script by enqueing it through functions.php